# simple clamp circuit resistor calculation

Tags: transistors, voltage-regulator, zener, clamp

Hello guys i want to calculate the resistor R in this circuit.Can anybody help me?

The value of zener diode(VZ)=4.8 volt.

[image: https://i.ibb.co/yQy22W2/Screenshot-27.png]

well i try to simplify  it

[image]
[image]

My question is is my solution is right??If not then what will be the value of R?

Comment: Your solution appears correct and provided you know all the values in eqn(1) (Vout, Vz and Rint) you can calculate R from eqn(2).

Comment: Why did you cut the connection between the top of the Zener and the collector of the transistor?